# Typo3 8.7: set/modify delete link in powermail (7.1.0)

Tags: typo3, powermail

I'm using the `powermail 7.1.0` extension for Typo3. When a customer now sends a powermail form, I send him an Email back with a specific response. At the end of my answer email appears a link and a text, which says

"Was this email a mistake and you want to delete your request?
Delete all email data."

and a Link to delete all the email data.

Now I can't remember setting this text nor the link and I'm having trouble finding the place where I can modify the text. I checked the `Mail to User` Section in the `Plugin Options` but the text is not there.

My goal is to change the text to german.

Is this auto-generated by `powermail`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new feature with powermail >= [7.0.0](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/Changelog/Index.html). You can deactivate it with `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.sender.addDisclaimerLink = 0`. To change the text you could do it for example in this partial [/Resources/Private/Partials/Mail/DisclaimerLink.html](https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Resources/Private/Partials/Mail/DisclaimerLink.html) or in your own language-file.

Comment: use `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.sender.addDisclaimerLink = 0`, I fixed it above..